# Relay Access Denied with virtual_alias_maps in postfix

Tags: postfix, email-server, smtp

My postfix server is encountering a problem with a couple domains bouncing email. The error message is:

```
postfix/smtpd[2673]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail.foo.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xx]: 554 5.7.1 < recipient@bar.com>: Relay access denied; from=<sender@foo.com> to=<recipient@bar.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail.foo.com>
```

the following is the result of postconf -n:

```
alias_database = hash:/usr/local/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/usr/local/etc/postfix/aliases, hash:/usr/local/etc/postfix/aliases-www
command_directory = /usr/local/sbin
config_directory = /usr/local/etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/local/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/db/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
html_directory = /usr/local/share/doc/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_command = /usr/local/bin/procmail
mailbox_size_limit = 524288000
mailq_path = /usr/local/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/local/man
message_size_limit = 40960000
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain 
myhostname = <<hostname here>>
mynetworks = <<list of server ip's>>
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/local/bin/newaliases
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/local/share/doc/postfix
sample_directory = /usr/local/etc/postfix
sendmail_path = /usr/local/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = maildrop
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/usr/local/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail
virtual_mailbox_limit = 524288000
```

I've checked to make sure the IP is listed in mynetworks and virtual_alias_maps has the address but the mail is still being rejected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But does `virtual_alias_maps` have the *domain*?  You can have all the addresses you want in there, but you haven't gotten as far as attempting delivery yet; Postfix is still trying to work out if the domain is one it's willing to accept.