# Replace explicit `virtual_alias_domains` by domains in `virtual_alias_maps`

Tags: postfix, domain, alias

I have a **working** Postfix config with some local mailboxes, some local aliases and a handful of purely virtual alias domains. Because I find it tedious to add all to `virtual_alias_domains` I'm asking: How to define them by simply using them in `virtual_alias_maps`?

Example:

```
### /etc/postfix/main.cf
myhostname = mx.example.com
virtual_alias_domains =
    foo.example
    bar.example
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

### /etc/postfix/virtual
single-user@foo.example single-user@example.com
@bar.example            whole-domain@example.com

# this one is missing in virtual_alias_domains and won't work
@baz.example            me@example.com
```

When adding new entries like `baz.example` I will probably forget to list them in `virtual_alias_domains`. This also breaks the common rule of [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

How to get rid of `virtual_alias_domains` or "compile it dynamically"?

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_domains says the default of `virtual_alias_domains` is `$virtual_alias_maps`:

> The default value is $virtual_alias_maps so that you can keep all information about virtual alias domains in one place.

But this seems not to work for me.

```
Jan 31 00:09:25 HOSTNAME postfix/smtpd[5064]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from FROM_HOSTNAME[185.XXX.XXX.XXX]: 454 4.7.1 <FROM_ADDRESS>:
  Relay access denied; from=<FROM_ADDRESS> to=<TO_ADDRESS> proto=ESMTP helo=<FROM_HOSTNAME>
```

(anonymized log, inserted newline for readability)
My actual configuration:

```
# postconf -n | egrep ^virtual_
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual 

# postconf | egrep ^virtual_alias
virtual_alias_address_length_limit = 1000
virtual_alias_domains = $virtual_alias_maps
virtual_alias_expansion_limit = 1000
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_alias_recursion_limit = 1000
```

Unfortunately I don't know to dump the configuration of `virtual_alias_domains` *after* variable expansion.

Comment: `virtual_alias_domains` should not be set at all. This part of your configuration is correct. The problem is going to be elsewhere.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Sounds good. Do you have any hints how to debug this?

Comment: You need to look at your `virtual_mailbox_` settings.

Comment: I had a look at the difference between  `virtual_alias_maps` and `virtual_mailbox_maps`. I am not sure which is more appropriate in my case. But I tried changing to `virtual_mailbox_maps` and it makes no differences: still relay access denied.

Comment: I just tried `virtual_mailbox_maps` with `virtual_mailbox_domains` for completeness' sake and it just doesn't work. So I stepped back to `virtual_alias_maps` but I still need to list all the domains.

Comment: I don't know what's going on; neither of your last two comments makes any sense to me. Please post your entire Postfix configuration so we can see what might be going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same problem.  [This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/293334) is correct but I wasn't quite understanding what it meant.

To use a single file for both `virtual_alias_maps` and `virtual_alias_domains`, you need to separately include each domain that you are forwarding for, without an `@`.  To keep Postfix happy, both a key and value are required, but for these domain entries the value can be anything you want, since Postfix is only checking for the existence of the key (the domain).

Example `/etc/postfix/virtual`:

```
# These are the virtual aliases:
single-user@foo.example single-user@example.com
@bar.example            whole-domain@example.com
@baz.example            me@example.com

# Repeat the bare domains:
foo.example             LITERALLY_ANYTHING
bar.example             LITERALLY_ANYTHING
baz.example             LITERALLY_ANYTHING
```

You could conceivably keep a file of just the alias mappings, and run it through a script to extract the domains and create the combined output file, but at that point you could also pass the domains to `postconf -e`, or put the domain entries in a separate file and run `postmap` on it, then tell `virtual_alias_domains` to use that file.  For me, adding the extra domain entries manually is fine, but it is nice to have it all in one place.

Comment: Not perfect, but far better than my original state. I have a lot of aliases configured—so I put the list of domains at the top of the hashmap file.